# Representing $\int \frac{\ln(x-1)}{x} dx$ as power series

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, power-series

I was requested to represent

$$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x} dx$$

as a power series with powers of $x$. Since I self-study, I don't have a professor to validate my solution and was wondering if someone could validate it here. I would greatly appreciate it.

$I$.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1-x) = -\frac{1}{1-x}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \implies \ln(1-x)=-\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

$II.$ Using $I$, we have

$$\begin{aligned}\int \frac{1}{x}\Big(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\Big) dx = -\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^2} = -\frac{x}{1} - \frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{x^3}{9}-...\end{aligned}$$

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks right to me: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+ln%281-x%29%2Fx+as+a+power+series

Comment: Just add the integration constant.